# Javascript Access Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
var array = [["ABC", "123"], ["DEF", "456"];
```

How can I get "123", if I look for "ABC?
I tried

```
array["ABC"][1] //Want Output: 123
array["DEF"][1] //Want Output: 456
```

Comment: Why don't you use an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
var array = [["ABC", "123"], ["DEF", "456"]];
let abc = array.find(x=>x[0]==="ABC");
console.log(abc?.[1]);
let def = array.find(x=>x[0]==="DEF");
console.log(def?.[1]);
let nothing = array.find(x=>x[0]==="NOTHING");
console.log(nothing?.[1]);
```

However, using an object or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is much better suited to this purpose. You can convert your array to an object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
var array = [["ABC", "123"], ["DEF", "456"]];
const obj = Object.fromEntries(array);
console.log(obj.ABC);
console.log(obj['DEF']);
```

You can pass the array to the `Map` constructor as well. `Map`s are better if you always want to retain insertion order.

```js
var array = [["ABC", "123"], ["DEF", "456"]];
const map = new Map(array);
console.log(map.get("ABC"));
console.log(map.get("DEF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to locate the item with the value at index `0`. If you found, return the value at index `1`.

```js
const findByFirstValue = (arr, val) =>
  ((res) => res ? res[1] : null)(arr.find(v => v[0] === val))

console.log(findByFirstValue([["ABC", "123"], ["DEF", "456"]], 'ABC'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`

```js
const array = [["ABC", "123"], ["DEF", "456"]];
const newMap = new Map();
array.map(item=>{
  newMap[item[0]] = item;
})
console.log(newMap['ABC'][1]);
```

Comment: Using `.map()` for its looping functionality isn't what `.map()` is supposed to be used for. You want to use `.forEach()` if you're not going to use the output of `.map()`, or, instead, pass the `Map` constructor a mapped array: `const newMap = new Map(array.map(([k, arr]) => [k, [k, arr]]))`

Comment: Also, to add entries to a `Map` you want to use `.set()` rather than bracket notation, as this will add keys/values to the underlying object, and not to the Map (you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Setting_object_properties))

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is impossible using array, you are not allowed to use:

```
array["ABC"]
```

since array's indexing is number based, you need to use objects in order to get what you want:

```
var array = {"ABC": ["123", "789"], "DEF": ["456", "323"]};
```

now you are able to select them as you want:

```
array['ABC'][1] // 123
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use index to get a value from array  in

```
//first level
// array[0] =>["ABC", "123"]
// array[1] => ["DEF", "456"]

//second level 
// array[0][0]=> "ABC"
// array[0][1]=>  "123"
```

also you can use methods like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
or  foreach